# Binding Services Quick Question

Tags: android

SO I am trying to bind a service with my application and I was wondering if its possible to bind that to every single activity (one service to 10 activities).

Thanks,
Arber

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should in fact be using the same code in each Activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bindService(new Intent(), new ServiceConnection(){
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        }
    }, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
}
```